# Converting an Array of hashes of hashes Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes of hashes. Here is what the structure looks like:

```
items = [{"Spaghetti & Meatballs"=>
   {
    :menu_item_name=>"Spaghetti & Meatballs",
    :quantity=>192,
    :category=>"delicious"}},
 {"Bananas"=>
   {
    :menu_item_name=>"Bananas",
    :quantity=>187,
    :category=>"sweet"}}]
```

I want to do the following:

```
items["Bananas"]
```

and return the hash at bananas.

Comment: you don't need the array, you can have `items = { "Bananas" => { menu_item_name: "Bananas", quantity: 187 }, "Spaghetti" => { menu_item_name: "Spaghetti", quantity: 192 } }`

Comment: This is how my data is sent to me, its in an array. I cannot change this.

Comment: @SebastianPalma, why is this question a duplicate? This question is not how to obtain a particular hash from an array of hashes (the subject of the linked question); it is how to make `items["Bananas"]` do that. (I just voted to reopen, and presto, it reopened. I didn't know I possessed magic dust.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would like `items["Banana"]` to return an array of elements (hashes) of `items` that have a key "Bananas". Let's consider how that would be done.

Since `items.class #=> Array` we would have to define an instance method `Array#[]` to do that. There's a problem, however: `Array` already has the instance method [Array#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5Dkm), which is used like so: `[1,2,3][1] #=> 2`, where the argument is the index of the array whose value is to be returned.

With the proviso that the hash's keys are not numeric, we could do the following.

```
class Array
  alias :left_right_paren :[]
  def [](x)
    if x.is_a?(Integer)
      left_right_paren(x)
    else
      find { |h| h.keys.include?(x) }
    end
  end
end

[1,2,3][1]
   #=> 2
items["Bananas"]
   #=> {"Bananas"=>{:menu_item_name=>"Bananas", :quantity=>187, :category=>"sweet"}}
```

All that remains is to decide whether this would be a good idea. My opinion? YUK!!

Answer (score 1):

With:

```
items = [{"Spaghetti & Meatballs"=>
   {
    :menu_item_name=>"Spaghetti & Meatballs",
    :quantity=>192,
    :category=>"delicious"}},
 {"Bananas"=>
   {
    :menu_item_name=>"Bananas",
    :quantity=>187,
    :category=>"sweet"}}]
```

Try:

```
items.find{|hsh| hsh.keys.first == "Bananas"}
```

In console:

```
2.3.1 :011 > items.find{|hsh| hsh.keys.first == "Bananas"}
 => {"Bananas"=>{:menu_item_name=>"Bananas", :quantity=>187, :category=>"sweet"}}
```

If you want, you could assign it to a variable:

```
bananas_hsh = items.find{|hsh| hsh.keys.first == "Bananas"}
```

Again, in console:

```
2.3.1 :012 > bananas_hsh = items.find{|hsh| hsh.keys.first == "Bananas"}
 => {"Bananas"=>{:menu_item_name=>"Bananas", :quantity=>187, :category=>"sweet"}} 
2.3.1 :013 > bananas_hsh
 => {"Bananas"=>{:menu_item_name=>"Bananas", :quantity=>187, :category=>"sweet"}}
```